# How to find the largest number in an array made by a ascendingly sorted array and a descendingly sorted array

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

for an array like `[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5]`, how do we efficiently find the largest number in it?
We know that the first part of the array is `1, 2, 4, 6,` which is ascendingly sorted and the second part is `8, 7, 5` which is a descendingly sorted array.

The simply solution would be iterate through the array, but given the array is made of two sorted array, I would image the search can be done by some sort of binary search variation to achieve `o(logn)` runtime complexity. However I cannot seem to come up with the solution.

Comment: you cannot use bbinary search on unsorted data

Comment: @sahasrara62 you cannot, but you can still use a divide and conquer style approach which is what OP is probably referring to. In this case the solution is actually a slightly modified version of binary search.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin that is probably merge sort he try to achive with less comlexity for this  kind of data

Comment: @sahasrara62 "Efficient Approach: Divide and Conquer can be used to find a peak in O(Logn) time. The idea is based on the technique of Binary Search to check if the middle element is the peak element or not.", you may want to read the article in the asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is equivalent to finding the "peak" of an array. [Here is logarithmic time](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-peak-in-a-given-array/) solution to the problem